# Operating system not found

Tags: operating-systems

I have installed original Windows 8 to my laptop. Today, when I start my laptop I am getting "Operating system not found" in black screen. What is the reason for this? Can anyone give any advice? Is the hard-disk crashed or are there some issues with the motherboard? How to resolve it?

Comment: Did you make a windows recovery disk when your system was operational? Windows simply does not crash in this fashion unless there is a hardware problem.  If you don't have a recovery disk, I would simply reinstall Windows, after you extra your personal files if they are present still.

Comment: @Ramhound Hey i have checked in Bios and hard-disk not found :( any idea?

Comment: This means the HDD is either dead or not connected.

Comment: @Ramhound Now what to do? :(

Comment: Verify the HDD is properly installed and if it is replace the HDD.